# Calling click method of Forms from from another class in project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I have a from application which i have written. This application also has a class which is basically a HTTP Server. I start this Http server in a separate thread in the Load function of the form.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpServer httpServer;
        httpServer = new MyHttpServer(8080);            
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(httpServer.listen));
        thread.Start();
    }
```

The problem i now have is that i want to be able to trigger the Click event on certain buttons on the form,  from the HttpServer class's functions where the requests come in. I am not able to do this as i do not have reference to the running Form1's objects in the HttpServer class.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: An HttpServer should not click buttons.  Have it generate events instead.  Now it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to create events in `HttpServer` class and subscribe to them, don't forget that code of event handlers will execute in another thread, so check `InvokeRequired` and use `Invoke/BeginInvoke` methods of form.

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the code in your Form1_Load method into a Service class.  Call this common service class from both places.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a reference to the form, you *can* make one. If you **can not** do that, for variou reasons, can extract the actions you execute in the Form's method into the separate class, that will be refered by Form and otjer compoenents of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Use events on your httpServer and have the form subscribe to them